# is it possible to check condition based on expression,objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, enumeration, nsexception

My arrays `arr`originally contains following

```
[A,B,C,D,E,F,G];
```

Now I want to remove A and B and C and I could do it like following

```
 [arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *name, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ( [name isEqualToString:@"A"] || [name isEqualToString:@"B"] || [name isEqualToString:@"C"]);
         [arr removeObject:name];
}];
```

Question : is it possible to do it using nsexpression. It sounds like to define an nsexpression contains A and B and C, then we delete elements based on the nxpression.

Any ideas how to achieve this. All comments are welcomed here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `NSExpression` directly, consider `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` or, for `NSMutableArray`, `filterUsingPredicate:`.  This will either return a new array filtered by the predicate, or the same array, mutated according to the predicate.

Also, it is not a real good idea to mutate your collection while enumerating.